# KeyCloak to send emails through MailChimp/Transactional emails templates

Tags: keycloak, mailchimp, mandrill

Has anyone used KeyCloak and then used an outside service like MailChimp as their template sending instead of using the KeyCloak built in Theme for the email sender?

We are using KeyCloak to send out the email verification for log ins, but it has it's own theme system that requires uses FreeMarker as it's base templates.

I am wondering if someone has used something like MailChimp/Mandrill (Transactional Emails), Sendgrid or other service to send the emails through so I don't have to build .jar files everytime I want to add a new email template to the KeyCloak system.  I would like to have the Mandrill service control the templates.
Right now Mandrill is set up as the SMTP sender, but there is not ties in right now for using specific templates, so it all comes through as plain text.